# Prove that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification, unique-factorization-domains

I want to prove that $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$. My attempt is to see that because $\mathbb{C}$ is UFD, then $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is UFD. However, in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z](y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$, because $y^2z = x(x^2-z^2)$ we have $(y)(y)(z) = (x)(x+z)(x-z)$, hence it is not an UFD and hence the two rings are not isomorphic.

Is this correct? Thanks

Comment: Why are the cosets of $y,z,x,x\pm z$ not associate to each other in the quotient ring in a manner that would make these two factorizations equivalent?

Comment: Is the fact that each is irreducible enough here @JyrkiLahtonen?

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what kind of arguments you can use, because a lot of context is missing. To me this quotient ring comes naturally from the (projective version of) the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-x$, but that is, perhaps/likely unusable in your course.

Comment: In the ring $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ the elements $2\pm i$ and $1\pm 2i$ are all irreducible, and
$$(2+i)(2-i)=5=(1+2i)(1-2i).$$ Yet $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD. Is it possible that something similar happens here?

Comment: Similarly, in the ring $\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(1-xy)$, the elements $(x)$ and $(y)$ are not irreducible because they are units. Have you ruled out this possibility also?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This comes from an algebraic geometry course, where I need to prove that $\mathbb{P}_1$ is not birational to $Z(Y^2Z-X^3+XZ^2)$. I know it is enough to check that their fractional fields are not isomorphic.

Comment: Is it due to the fact that the ideal is homogeneous?

Comment: The ideal being homogeneous does play a role. Homogeneity implies that the quotient ring inherits the natural grading from $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$. That does imply that the cosets of linear polynomials are all irreducible - much the same way why linear polynomials are irreducible in general. That should also help in proving that the two factorizations you have are inequivalent. But I'm a bit rusty with all this :-)

Comment: Isn't quite clear that the two (graded) rings have different Hilbert series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$ is probably not a UFD, but in any case you still have to prove that the elements $x,y,z,x-z,x+z$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$, which may not be immediate...

So let me give you an easier argument. The ideal $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ strictly contains $(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$, so it gives rise to a nonzero ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$. Moreover, the latter is a nonmaximal prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$, because $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x,y) \cong \mathbb{C}[z]$ is an integral domain which is not a field.

However, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a PID, so in particular every nonzero prime ideal is maximal. Therefore, $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y^2z-x^3+xz^2)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$\left(\mathbb{C}\left[x,y,z\right]/\left(x^{3}-xz^{2}-y^{2}z\right)\right)/\left(x,y,z\right)^{2}\ \simeq\ \mathbb{C}\left[x,y,z\right]/\left(x,y,z\right)^{2}.$$ But the ideal $$\left(x,y,z\right)\ \subseteq\  \mathbb{C}\left[x,y,z\right]/\left(x,y,z\right)^{2}$$ is clearly nonprincipal, so the latter can’t be quotient of any PID, QED.

(Alternatively, think of this argument as computing the dimension of the Zariski cotangent space of $\mathbb{C}\left[x,y,z\right]/\left(x^{3}-xz^{2}-y^{2}z\right)$ at the point $\left(x,y,z\right)\subseteq \mathbb{C}\left[x,y,z\right]/\left(x^{3}-xz^{2}-y^{2}z\right)$.)